# Solr spell check multi word query with some correct words

Tags: solr, spell-checking

Suppose a user does a search for something like:

```
red computor
```

"red" is spelled correctly, but "computor" is not.  I have the following configuration for the spell checker:

```
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">spelling</str>
  <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
  <str name="accuracy">0.5</str>
  <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
  <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
  <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
  <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
</lst>
```

The query I am issuing is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/spell?q=computor+red&wt=json&indent=true&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true
```

Because "red" is spelled correctly, I get results for documents relating to "red" but I do not get any spelling suggestions for the misspelled term, "computor".  If I change, "red" to something incorrect like "reeed" I get spelling suggestions for "reeed" and "computor", but if one term appears to be spelled correctly, then I get no suggestions at all.

How do I reconfigure either my query or the spell checker to run the spell checker on each incoming term in the query?

Comment: Have you found solution for this ?

Comment: I have not found a solution for this using solr.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue like this but have found a solution using solr.

First upgrade solr version to latest Solr-6.1.0 if you are using old version.

If you are using IndexBasedSpellChecker, then you should have word **computer** in your documents. by index="true" in field type.

For the proper spellchecking change,

```
accuracy => 0.001
minCount => 1
maxCollationTries => 1
maxCollations => 1
```

and remove this, if not required for now

```
<int name="maxEdits">2</int>
<int name="minPrefix">1</int>
<int name="maxInspections">5</int>
```

Add this code below indexBasedSpellcheckerComponent,

```
<!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
  <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
  <str name="field">spelling</str>
  <str name="combineWords">true</str>
  <str name="breakWords">true</str>
  <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
</lst>

<!-- Example of using different distance measure -->
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">spelling</str>
  <str name="field">lowerfilt</str>
  <!-- Use a different Distance Measure -->
  <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance</str>
  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
</lst>
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the value of parameter `spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest` which will prevent suggestions if there are "enough" search results. Try for example adding to your configuration:

```
<int name="maxResultsForSuggest">500</int>
```